# Group mean centering predictors for crossed random effects

Tags: mixed-model, random-effects-model, centering

I'm fitting a mixed-effects model, in which I wish to test the effect of $X$ on $Y$, with crossed random intercepts and slopes for each subjects $S%$, and for each level of an additional grouping variable, $P$.

The value of $Y$, on trial $i$, for $subject \ =s$, and $P = p$, is

$$Y_{i, s, p} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \times X_i$$

$$\beta_0 = \gamma_0 + \beta_{0s} + \beta_{0p}$$

$$\beta_1 = \gamma_1 + \beta_{1s} + \beta_{1p}$$
With the intercept, $\beta_0$ composed of the intercept $\gamma_0$, plus random
deviations from this for subject $s$, and $p$,
and likewise for $\beta_1$, the slope of $X$.

Now, at some values of $P$,
the range of $X$ is restricted,
so I would like to be able to center $X$ and $Y%
for my analysis.

My initial idea was that I could parcel up my
data as follows:

```
|     || S=1 | S=2 | S=3 | S=4 | S=5 |
|-----+|-----+-----+-----+-----+-----|
| P=1 || a   | b   | c   | d   | e   |
| P=2 || f   | g   | h   | i   | j   |
| P=3 || k   | l   | m   | n   | o   |
| P=4 || p   | q   | r   | s   | t   |
| P=5 || u   | v   | w   | x   | y   |
```

with, for example, cell `a` containing data from subject 1, under condition $P=1$, and within each cell centre both $X$ and $Y$ by subtracting their mean within the cell.
I then went on to fit a new model, with $x$ and $y$ replaced by their cell mean centred 
alternatives, and the intercept terms eliminated as no longer needed after centring:

$$Centred.Y_{i, s, p} = \beta_1 \times Centred.X_i$$

To rephrase this, using R:

```
# Group mean centre a variable
gmc = function(variable, group){
    return(ave(variable, group, FUN = function(x){x - mean(x)}))
}

data$s.p = interaction(data$s, data$p)
data$gmc.x = gmc(data$x, data$s.p)
data$gmc.y = gmc(data$y, data$s.p)

model = lmer(gmc.y ~ gmc.x - 1 +
                (gmc.x - 1 | s) +
                (gmc.x - 1 | p),
              data = data)
```

---

While I believe I can see the logic in how I've done this in my own head, I'm having a hard time finding any literature on the topic, and as this is part of quite a large project, don't want to be running in the wrong direction.

Can anyone either

- Find fault with my approach, or
- Point to previous work on centring variables with crossed random effects.